# Laravel Application on Oracle WebLogic Server

Tags: java, php, oracle, laravel, weblogic

please i need someone to highlight firstly how i could execute php 5.x on Oracle Weblogic J2EE server and the settings required if any...

its a java based environment and i'm wondering how i could get this up and running seamlessly.

if you could provide in details the process required to get Apache working, alongside PHP, my intentions is to use it as the base for a Laravel application i'm currently working on and utilize Oracle as the backend database model...

any ideas ?

Comment: The Oracle Weblogic Server is an application server which runs in a OS, so it doesn't really matter at this point. The thing that matters is what OS are you running, because the instructions for setting up a HTTP server + PHP environment will be specific for the OS.

Comment: wondering if that really matters, since i'd be developing on windows, and deploying on linux OS... i just need to set up the environment on my workstation at the moment and i'm lost on how that is done...

Comment: To keep it simple, if you're setting up on Windows just install [XAMPP for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html), then if you have any problems setting up the Laravel app in the environment just follow [this article](http://tutsnare.com/how-to-install-laravel-on-windows-xampp/).